# GREP How to print words which started with some string?

Tags: grep

How to print words which started with some string? For example, started with `do`.

My text file:

```
domino
doleto
defrad
domes
depo
dewalk
dorio
```

Output:

```
domino
doleto
domes
dorio
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

begin the search string with ^  , for example "^do"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep '^do' file
```

The character ^ indicates that the line must beging with do.

Comment: But this command prin also words with "do" in the middle of the word. I just need words which begin with "do"

Comment: This command prints words with a "do" in th middle of the word if that word starts with a "do". For example "doredo" will be printed, but "torpedo" don't.